# pip install ok, but "insecure and unverifiable files" on travis.ci

Tags: python, pip, travis-ci

I created and uploaded a package  callled [pdfminer.six on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=pdfminer.six&version=20140915&:action=display)

It installs correctly through "pip install pdfminer.six" on my PC (Windows)
and [passes tests on travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/goulu/pdfminer)

Since I need this package for my other project (Goulib), I added "pdfminer.six" it to its requirements.txt, but [Travis.ci fails importing this package](https://travis-ci.org/goulu/Goulib/jobs/35333581) ) :

> Downloading/unpacking pdfminer.six (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
>
> Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pdfminer.six
>
> (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) Some insecure and unverifiable
>
> files were ignored (use --allow-unverified pdfminer.six to allow).
>
> Cleaning up... No distributions at all found for pdfminer.six (from -r
>   requirements.txt (line 7))

Tried to add --allow-unverified and version number ==20140915 in all possible ways, no change ...

What should I do to make pdfminer.six "secure and verifiable" on Travis-ci ?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this manually using just pip, and I'm getting similar results:

    `~$ pip install pdfminer.six --allow-unverified pdfminer.six --allow-all-external
    Downloading/unpacking pdfminer.six
      Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pdfminer.six
    Cleaning up...
    No distributions at all found for pdfminer.six
    Storing debug log for failure in /home/travis/.pip/pip.log`

Looking at the pypi page, there is no release for pdfminer.six yet on pypi.python.org, is that correct?

Comment: me stupid :-( I trusted what I saw :

running upload
Submitting dist\pdfminer.six-20140919.zip to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK

but it wasn't uploaded correctly. Just have to find why...
Thanks !